# JavaScriptでクリックされた要素のindexを取得したい

Tags: javascript

```
<ul>
    <li>チョコレート</li>
    <li>バニラ</li>
    <li>ストロベリー</li>
    <li>バナナ</li>
</ul>
```

上記の`<li>`がクリックされたとき、liが何番目であるかJavascript（jQueryは使わない）で取得したいです。
方法ご存知のかたがおられましたらご教示お願いします。

Comment: [このページ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498027/find-the-number-of-an-li-element-in-an-unordered-list)に英語で同じ質問をしている人がいましたよ。

Answer (score 2):

**li**の配列の何番目に**event.target**と一致する内容が存在するか検索することで取得できます。
チョコレートは0番目になるので、1番目としたい場合は、取得した値に+1してください。

```js
function chooseItem(event) {
  var ul = event.target.parentNode;
  var li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");
  console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(li, event.target));
}
```

```html
<ul onclick="chooseItem(event)">
  <li>チョコレート</li>
  <li>バニラ</li>
  <li>ストロベリー</li>
  <li>バナナ</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul`は複数存在し得るので、`event.target.parentNode`を使うべきかと思います。

Comment: その方がより親切ですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

かなりシンプルなバージョンになりますが、こちらのコードでクリックされたリストアイテムの`id`が取得できます。

```js
function myFunction(event) { 
    alert(event.target.id); //チョコレートをクリックした場合item1が表示されます
}
```

```html
<ul onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <li id="item1">チョコレート</li>
    <li id="item2">バニラ</li>
    <li id="item3">ストロベリー</li>
    <li id="item4">バナナ</li>
</ul>
```